# How to save downloaded Excel file data from Data table into application folder in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want downloaded file into save application folder here I downloaded file as Excel sheet from data table. I didn't take path to file download it's directly download from data table and I want to save it in application folder. How can I do this?

My code:

```
 public void ExportToExcel(DataSet ds)
        {           
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                {
                    //Add DataTable as Worksheet.
                    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
                }
                //Export the Excel file.
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xlsx");                
                using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);                  
                    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Report.xlsx"));// I added this but it shows error
                    Response.Flush();                 
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't actually named the file you want to transmit. Only the directory path is showing there

Comment: Hi @DiskJunky, when i take file name also it's shows `Could not find file`

Comment: Then that means that the file cannot be located in that path. If you take the contents of `Server.MapPath()` and put them into a string variable before `Response.TransmitFile()`, you'll get the path it resolves to. If you navigate in Windows Explorer, is the file there?

Comment: Here for downloading file i didn't take path it's downloads direct from data table. could you please see my code. I want put the downloaded file into application folder

Comment: Yes I am not saving the file anywhere. i am downloading direct from the data table actually i need to send this downloaded file with mail attachment so i decide to save downloaded file within application folder after i need to attach the path to mail attachments

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're looking for. Are you downloading the Excel file from an MVC controller or creating an email?

Answer (score 0):

It took a while to make sense of the order of things but removing the call to `TransmitFile()` should work. You're already writing out the file via the `MemoryStream`.

```
    public void ExportToExcel(DataSet ds)
    {           
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                //Add DataTable as Worksheet.
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
            }
            //Export the Excel file.
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xlsx");                
            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);                  
                Response.Flush();                 
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

If this is a standard MVC controller action then your response is much easier and changes to;

```
    public FileStreamResult ExportToExcel(DataSet ds)
    {           
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                //Add DataTable as Worksheet.
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
            }
            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                return FileStreamResult(MyMemoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I am I have tables in data set i am taking it into data table those rows directly downloading as a excel sheet

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The solution is based on the original code in how the workbook is created. From the workbook it goes to a `MemoryStream` and from there, written directly to the request to download the file.

Comment: Hi, @DiskJunky, this is my requirement, I need to generate a excel sheet so i want to export data into excel sheet at same time  that same sheet i need to download and send as like mail attachment. Thank you

Comment: @User777 I still can't understand what's required here. Create an Excel file, yes. Download the Excel file, yes. Email? Where's this in the code?

Comment: ,Sorry, I didn't do that mail code i am telling you to my actual requirement now i completed my requirement and thank you for giving replies